# How to create point feature from longitude/latitude coordinates using ArcObjects and VB.net?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vb.net

i Want to add a point feature to my feature class. an i want to enter the coordinates manually.

here is what i am trying to do

```
    pworkspaceedit = pFeatureWorkspace
    pworkspaceedit.StartEditing(True)
    pworkspaceedit.StartEditOperation()

    Dim point As IPoint = New Point
    Dim geometry As IGeometry

    point.X = 100
    point.Y = 100

    geometry = point

    pfeature = pFeatureClass.CreateFeature()

    pfeature.Shape = geometry

    MsgBox(pFeatureClass.FeatureCount(Nothing))
    pworkspaceedit.StopEditOperation()
    pworkspaceedit.StopEditing(True)
```

i have searched and the results are for copying from one feature class to another using icursor, creating lines from points, but havent found one for creating a point feature. all suggestions are welcome

there is no error in the code, a new empty feature is also created, but it has no attributes, MsgBox(pFeatureClass.FeatureCount(Nothing)) this i am using to display the no. of features after its created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing one step. You need to **store** the geometry to write it to the feature class. There are various ways to do this, but the easiest way in your situation is to invoke the IFeature.Store() method. Here's some other stuff:

- I assume your pFeature is an IFeature, but just to be sure we'll explicity declare it.
- From documentation, point X and point Y properties are get/set, so the way you are setting your coordinates looks fine, but just for kicks lets use the method that was designed to set coordinates: IPoint.PutCoords().
- Finally, you should be able to directly store an IPoint in the shape property of IFeature without having to move it to an IGeometry.

Try this:

```
pworkspaceedit = pFeatureWorkspace
pworkspaceedit.StartEditing(True)
pworkspaceedit.StartEditOperation()

Dim point As IPoint = New Point

point.PutCoords(100, 100)

Dim pfeature As IFeature = pFeatureClass.CreateFeature()

pfeature.Shape = point
feature.Store() 

MsgBox(pFeatureClass.FeatureCount(Nothing))
pworkspaceedit.StopEditOperation()
pworkspaceedit.StopEditing(True)
```